# Finding a file starting with '-' dash

Tags: filenames, options

I have the following situation:

```
$ ls
0.txt  aaa.txt  a-.txt  a.txt  b.txt  ddd.txt  -hello.txt  libs  -.txt  ,.txt  !.txt  ].txt  \.txt
$ ls [-a]*.txt
ls: opzione non valida -- "e"
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
$ ls [a-]*.txt
ls: opzione non valida -- "e"
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
```

The dash (`-`) creates some problems. How can I find a file starting with `-`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `--` to indicate end of options for `ls`:

```
ls -- -*
```

or do the following to explicitly indicate the argument on current directory with `./`

```
ls ./-*
```

If you want to input more options for `ls`, put them before `--` or `./` e.g.

```
ls -l -- -*
ls -l ./-*
```

Comment: forget --, use ./, as it is more portable

Comment: @OlivierDulac Unless you're working with 1970s (1980s?) systems, no, `--` is portable.

Comment: Do we really not have a canonical "how do I escape `-`" question I can flag this as a duplicate of? It seems like we have had one of these questions every week for a while

Comment: @Gilles: well, the added advantage of going the "./" route is that you don't have to 1) ensure *all* the command you use know about "--"  2) same for any possible function of the same name ... I keep using that way. But one still needs to **also** use the '--' in one's function to clearly mark the end of options, ensuring a parameter won't affect the function's behaviour. ie, we need both: `something ./*` on the command line, to properly designate the files we want to affect, and `somecommand [options here] -- "$@"` in our function definitions, where -- clearly delimitate options from args

Comment: And I did encounter commands ignoring what "--" was meant to be, but I'll have to research about those at work, as I can't remember which command it was (an ancient aix tar, maybe?)

Comment: If you're doing this in a shell script, [shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck) will actually warn you that this is a possibility