# Filter columns basing on the value of other column

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, grep, cp

I have a text file with two columns and more than 3,00,000 rows. Format is as below

```
Filename1.txt Num1
Filename2.txt Num2
Filename3.txt Num3
```

I want to copy all the filenames for which the corresponding `Numx` is greater than 50 and less than 200 into a different file.

Once I copy those file names into a different file, I want to copy all of those files into a different folder.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want you can do the comparison and copying at the same time with `awk`:

```
awk '$2>50 && $2<200 {system("cp -- "$1" /path/to/destination/")}' file.txt
```

Assuming you want to copy the files to `destination` directory, change this to meet your need.

- `$2>50 && $2<200` does the required comparison
- if matches, then the `cp` operation is executed (`{system("cp -- "$1" /path/to/destination/")}`), done by the `system()` function of `awk`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. What does -- in cp means?

Comment: @Innocent It is there to tackle any filename beginning with `-`.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What does tackling here mean?

Comment: @Innocent see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/313687/68757

Comment: Marked. I am not sure if it will be recorded. I am a new user and it gives me some 15 reputation min requirement etc.

Comment: @Innocent Welcome to Unix and Linux. The reputations are your achievements. Please [take a tour of the site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour). Hope to see you regularly here.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider this test file:

```
$ cat file
Filename1.txt 49
Filename2.txt 72
Filename3.txt 189
Filename4.txt 203
```

To select only those files for which the second column is greater than or equal to 50 and also less than or equal to 200:

```
$ awk '$2>=50 && $2<=200 { print $1}' file
Filename2.txt
Filename3.txt
```

To put those file names in a new file at some path:

```
awk '$2>=50 && $2<=200 { print $1}' file >/path/to/newfile
```

#### Copying the selected files

Assuming that the numbers are integers, try:

```
while read fname num; do [ "$num" -ge 50 ] && [ "$num" -le 200 ] && cp -- "$fname" /some/path/ ; done <file
```

Or, for those who prefer their code spread over multiple lines:

```
while read fname num
do
   [ "$num" -ge 50 ] && [ "$num" -le 200 ] && cp -- "$fname" /some/path/
done <file
```

Comment: You got first part of my question right. Regarding the second part, I want to copy all those "files" itself into a different folder.

Comment: @Innocent See update for a way to move the files.

Answer (score 0):

The question is tagged [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) and [grep](/questions/tagged/grep), so I assume there is interest in an answer that uses regular expressions.  Also the question indicates the input data file is large and so I assume that performance is a consideration.

I also assume that given that the input file contains one filename per line that there will be no (pathological) filenames that contain newline characters.

The other answers effectively spawn a `cp` process for every file.  This causes unnecessary performance reduction.  Instead we can use the facilities of `xargs` to call `cp` with as many filenames as it can fit on a command line.

```
sed -rn 's/ (5[1-9]|[6-9].|1..)$//p' input.txt | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 cp -t /destdir
```

The `sed` uses a regular expression to match the closed numerical interval `(50, 200)`.  Using regular expressions for numerical inequalities is not always the most elegant thing to do, but in this case the required expression is fairly straightforward.

We are assuming that the filenames contain no newlines, but they may contain other unhelpful characters, such as spaces.  `xargs` will handle this correctly if given `\0`-delimited data, so we use `tr` to convert all newlines to null characters.

The above assumes the GNU versions of `sed` and `xargs`.  If instead you have BSD versions (e.g. OSX), then the command is slightly different:

```
sed -En 's/ (5[1-9]|[6-9].|1..)$//p' input.txt | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -J {} cp {} /destdir
```

These commands will spawn exactly one copy of `sed`, `tr` and `xargs`.  There will be more than one spawn of `cp`, but each one will copy multiple files - `xargs` will attempt to fill up each `cp` command line to acheive efficient utilisation.  This should provide a significant performance improvement over the other answers when the input data is large.